# promise - then method using resolve reject method vs if/else

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I'm new to javascript and I've self taught the promise API (asynchronous operation). yet I'm a little but confused with result handling in then method especially for rejection.

does the 2 following examples the equivalent ? (I just need an explanation)

**exp1:**

```
promise.then(
  (result) => { 
     console.log(result);
  },
  (error) => { 
     console.log(error);
  }
);
```

**exp2**

```
promise.then(
  (result) => { 
    if (result.ok) {
     console.log(result);
  } else {
     console.log('error');
  });
```

for **exp1** there are the use of 2 arguments in then (result & error), for the **exp2** only one argument but it is considering success & fail in same bloc **result** which is imo the fulfilled

Comment: The second one is not valid. unbalanced braces; reference to undefined variable `resp`, and `ok` is a  property that will depend on what the resolved value is -- it is not a generic thing. Probably something you use with `fetch`.

Comment: typo aside, not equivalent, exp1 handles rejections, exp2 does not

Comment: A `Promise` failing is not the same thing as a `Promise` successfully resolving to a custom object which internally indicates that something else failed.

Comment: @trincot yes the example is used with fetch

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks! this is what I wanted to know indeed, a confirmation, what if I wanted to convert **exp2** similar to **exp1** I mean to handle rejection

Comment: It may be a little confusing and move rather fast (it's an introduction more than an explanation or tutorial), but ["JavaScript Promises: an introduction"](https://web.dev/promises/) may be helpful. (Especially the error handling part.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are looking at specific promises -- ones that intend to resolve with an object that has an `ok` key. For example, this is what `fetch()` does.

The differences:

- The first code does not check the value of this `ok` key, and so if the promise fulfils with `result.ok` equal to `false`, then the output will be different. The first code snippet will in that case (when `ok` is false) log the `result` object (where we will see `ok` is `false`), the second code snippet will log "error".
- The second code does not deal with rejections, so that if the promise rejects, the first one will output "error", while the second will raise an "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError".

Note that the `ok` key that `fetch` provides in its response is an indication that it received an HTTP response, while a rejection means there was a more fundamental error.

If you want to execute the catch handler in case the `ok` key is `false`, then chain promises like this:

```
fetch("https://httpstat.us/405").then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) { // Throwing an error will reject the chained promise:
        throw new TypeError("The 'ok' key is false, and 'status' is " + response.status);
    }
    console.log(response);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log("############### OOPS ######################");
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: "**if the promise fulfils with `!result.ok` then the output will be different**" can you explain how would it be different ?

Comment: on the other hand, if `result.ok` is `true` does it mean that the promise is **fulfilled** & if `result.ok` is `false` the promise is **rejected** ?

Comment: When the `then` callback executes, you already know the `fetch()` promise fulfilled. This is unrelated to an `ok` key. `then()` returns a new promise (to be distinguished from what `fetch()` returns), and we can influence whether that promise fulfils or reject by what we do in the `then` callback. I added a phrase in my answer concerning the different output in the first bullet point.

Comment: why assuming result.of is false "**where we will see ok is false**" ?

Comment: There is no assumption that `result.ok` will be false, but if you have *checked* with the `if` statement that it actually *is* false, and then print the result object, then of course we will see it is false.